# How to temporarily unsubscribe to Stream after Navigator.of(context).push(....)?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

**Scenario** : There are two pages. `PhonePage` and `OtpPage` . User inputs phone number in `PhonePage` and gets redirected to `OtpPage` to verify the OTP sent to him.

**Problem**: The API that talks to the server uses a `StreamController.broadcast()` to tell the app the response of the request. This Stream is shared by both `PhonePage` and `OtpPage` and produces events. The two pages listen to the stream and decide what to do based on the event.

However, after `Navigator.push()`, the old page is still listening to the stream. Thus when user in `OtpPage` taps the resend button, `Navigator.push` in `PhonePage` is still called although it should not.

**Question** What does Flutter has to deal with such scenario ? I tried `onDispose()` but it does not get called.
I would appreciate if you could also explain why `onDispose` is not called too.

**Code**: this is the code to reproduce the scenario. You can just paste it on your IDE or DartPad https://dartpad.dev/flutter (Note: When you go to `OtpPage`  and some text on the text field, the click on resend button. Notice how a new `OtpPage` Widget is added on top the Navigator tree. That's the unwanted behaviour )

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final fakeApiResponse = StreamController.broadcast();

void main() => runApp(MyApp(),);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PhoneNumber(),
    );
  }
}

class PhoneNumber extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhoneNumberState createState() => _PhoneNumberState();
}

class _PhoneNumberState extends State<PhoneNumber> {
  StreamSubscription apiEventListner;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text('Enter your phone number'),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Send OTP'),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Sent');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiEventListner = fakeApiResponse.stream.listen((data) {
      if (data == 'OTP Sent') {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => VerifyOtp(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    apiEventListner.cancel();
  }
}

class VerifyOtp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifyOtpState createState() => _VerifyOtpState();
}

class _VerifyOtpState extends State<VerifyOtp> {
  StreamSubscription apiEventListner;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter OTP Here'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Verify"),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Verified');
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Didn't get the code? Resend OTP"),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Sent');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiEventListner = fakeApiResponse.stream.listen((data) {
      if (data == 'OTP Sent') {
        // show the dialog
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return  AlertDialog(
              title: Text("OTP Resent"),
              content: Text("Enter new OTP"),

            );
          },
        );
      }else if (data == 'OTP Verified'){
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SuccessPage()));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    apiEventListner.cancel();
  }
}

class SuccessPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('SUCCESS!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the Api code as it is a library so I don't have a control on the response event name. The Api only knows one thing: Send Otp will respond with Otp Sent.  It does not have the concept of Resend Otp. You just have to call Send Otp again to resend it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I am going to post anyways it here in case it might be helpful for someone else.

The trick is to detect the current active route and return if the current widget is not the current route inside the listeners of the Streams.

Flutter has an API called `ModalRoute route = ModalRoute.of(context);` then `route.isCurrent` will be true if the current widget is the current route.

Then you have to add this check in **both** pages.

The final working code would be:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final fakeApiResponse = StreamController.broadcast();

void main() => runApp(
      MyApp(),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PhoneNumber(),
    );
  }
}

class PhoneNumber extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhoneNumberState createState() => _PhoneNumberState();
}

class _PhoneNumberState extends State<PhoneNumber> {
  StreamSubscription apiEventListner;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text('Enter your phone number'),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Send OTP'),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Sent');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiEventListner = fakeApiResponse.stream.listen((data) {
      ModalRoute route = ModalRoute.of(context);
      String name = route?.settings?.name;
      print("Phone page isCurrent: ${route?.isCurrent} isFirst: ${route?.isFirst} active: ${route?.isActive} $name");
      if (route?.isCurrent != null && !route.isCurrent) {
        return;
      }
      if (data == 'OTP Sent') {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => VerifyOtp(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    apiEventListner.cancel();
  }
}

class VerifyOtp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifyOtpState createState() => _VerifyOtpState();
}

class _VerifyOtpState extends State<VerifyOtp> {
  StreamSubscription apiEventListner;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter OTP Here'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Verify"),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Verified');
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Didn't get the code? Resend OTP"),
            onPressed: () {
              fakeApiResponse.add('OTP Sent');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiEventListner = fakeApiResponse.stream.listen((data) {
      ModalRoute route = ModalRoute.of(context);
      String name = route?.settings?.name;
      print("OTP page isCurrent: ${route?.isCurrent} isFirst: ${route?.isFirst} active: ${route?.isActive} $name");
      if (route?.isCurrent != null && !route.isCurrent) {
        return;
      }
      if (data == 'OTP Sent') {
        // show the dialog
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("OTP Resent"),
              content: Text("Enter new OTP"),
            );
          },
        );
      } else if (data == 'OTP Verified') {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SuccessPage()));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    apiEventListner.cancel();
  }
}

class SuccessPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('SUCCESS!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```